# How to address Java String instantiation issue reported by Sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have used the below statement in my code to declare an empty string.

```
String temp = new String();
```

This has led to an issue raised by Sonarqube.
So what would be the efficient way to fix this ?
Is the below declaration a good way?

```
String temp = "";
```

Comment: Doesn't Sonar(Qube) provide you with some information as to why they flag that line as 'not recommended' ?

Comment: There is never a good reason to use `new String()`... Yes, `""` is the empty `String` and will use the intern cache.

Comment: Without context, it would be hard to advise a good replacement.  But initializing to empty string would be preferable to `new String()` in most cases.

Comment: @MadConan In most of the cases, i have nested if else Statements which will decide the value to be assigned to temp.

Comment: Would you mind precising the rule key raising the issue ? that could help to improve the documentation of this rule.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar is correct in that you shouldn't be using `new String()`.  Initializing to empty string (`String temp = ""`) is better.  But if you do not use the value of empty string in any case, you should not initialize the variable to anything.  You should only initialize a variable to a value you intend to use.

This is perfectly, and usually, acceptable:

```
String temp;
```

Your conditional logic should cover all cases of assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
     * an empty character sequence.  Note that use of this constructor is
     * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
     */
    public String() {
        this.value = new char[0];
    }
```

Above souce code of String class depicts that **use of this constructor is unnecessary**. Every time you will create new object in heap. Better is to use String pool.

Answer (score 0):

The second example is the correct one.

Use

```
String temp = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sonar is correct. Using `new String()` is pretty much never a good idea.

The reason for this is, that the JVM caches Strings, so that you don't need to create a new object on the heap every time (this is why sometimes wrongly comparing strings with `==` works - They are both referring to the same cached instance on the heap).

Constructing a String yourself will circumvent that built-in cache and can lead to performance problems down the line. If all you need is an empty String just assign it:

```
String temp = "";
```

Or, if you just want to declare a String since you want to assign it later, just don't assign anything to it!

```
String temp;
if(condition()) {
    temp = "hello!";
} else {
    temp = "bye!";
}
```

If you plan on concatenating to your empty String in a loop though read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java) about the attached performance issues and how to handle them.